# SCRIPT1014: Invalid character

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this script:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var ae = jQuery('#featured-right a.active');
    if ( ae.length == 0 ) {
        ae = jQuery('#featured-right a:first');
        var i = jQuery('#featured-right a').index(ae);
        var bae = jQuery('#featured-left a.fb-'+i);
        bae.show();
    }

    var ne =  ae.next().length ? ae.next() : jQuery('#featured-right a:first');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var ae = jQuery('#featured-right a.active');
    if ( ae.length == 0 ) {
        ae = jQuery('#featured-right a:first');
        ae.addClass('active');
        var i = jQuery('#featured-right a').index(ae);
        jQuery('#featured-left a.fb-'+i).show();
        jQuery('#featured-right a:not(.active) span.key').hide();
    }
    setInterval("slideSwitch()", 1000);  
});
```

which works great on any browser but IE. On IE, IU get

```
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character featured.js, line 1 character 1
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Off-topic but related to your code: You should never pass a string to `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. Pass a function instead. In your case: `setInterval(slideSwitch, 1000);`, if you needed to pass arguments: `setInterval(function(){ /*whatever you want to do, e.g. calling a function */ }, 1000);`

Comment: Got this because I tried using  as a variable name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that IE didn't like the fact that i was accessing the page without a HTTP server :)
I was accessing c:\www\my-file. When accessing http://localhost/my-file .. worked great.

Comment: I have the same problem and having the file online solves it as you said. But is there anyway of getting this to work without having to put the file online?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can have a http server installed locally and access it through localhost/...

Comment: @Clox : Thank you so much. Do you know why a simple cache cleanup is solving the issue? I'm curious.

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem. It said there was an error in line 1 row 1 of the main file. I use a ton of AJAX in the page I was using.

It all boiled down to the fact that I had **onclick="#"** on an A tag. Once I removed that, the error went away.

I think when jQuery loads the html via an AJAX call, it takes the onclick tags and processes the javascript it finds inside.

Answer (score 8):

Watch out for template string literals.  This error was caused by a

```
`
```

character for me in IE11.

Comment: But in this case the line and character indexes are correct (e.g. 41,5) and not just (1,1). If you have this problem and want your code to work in IE11, you can transpile it with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is likely to be that the file is UTF-8 encoded and the file is being brought in via a script tag which doesn't define this encoding.  If you add `charset="UTF-8"` as an attribute to the importing script tag hopefully that'll fix it.

Comment: IE9.x running / developing locally (a location on my C: drive). Fails.  Works from http resource. Downloaded files locally to work on them. Tried everything. Refresh.  Empty cache and refresh. Chrome works. Checked encoding, not UTF-8. Opened file in Notepad++ saved as ASCII. Still didn't work. Have proper doctype. From Notepad++ did a select all...copy...pasted to new file, saved as ASCII.  Still didn't work.  Seems like a problem from local.  Copied to an SD Card /F: drive and loaded page from IE.  Worked fine.  Copied to my C:\temp directory, worked fine. Still won't work from orig. path.