# Invalid character script1014 (in IE) with simple jquery VAT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

trying to get this code to fire but i keep getting console errors referring to the last line of the code but it seems fine to me, have been testing different combinations but to no avail, anyone any insight :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    $("#txtModalPricesIncPrice").keyup(function() {

        var price = $(this).val();
        var VAT = (parseFloat($("#txtModalPricesVAT").attr("value"))/100)+1;
        $("#txtModalPricesExPrice").val(price / VAT);


    });

    $("#txtModalPricesExPrice").keyup(function() {

        var price = $(this).val();
        var VAT = (parseFloat($("#txtModalPricesVAT").attr("value"))/100)+1;

        $("#txtModalPricesIncPrice").val(price * VAT);

    });

    $("#txtModalPricesVAT").keyup(function() {

        var price1 = $("#txtModalPricesIncPrice").val();
        var price2 = $("#txtModalPricesExPrice").val;
        var VAT = (parseFloat($("#txtModalPricesVAT").attr("value"))/100)+1;

        $("#txtModalPricesIncPrice").val(price1 * VAT);
        $("#txtModalPricesExPrice").val(price2 / VAT);

    });
</script>
```

table code is as follows

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead><th></th><th></th></thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Product ID: </td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtModalPricesProductID" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description: </td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtModalPricesDesc" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price Level: </td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtModalPricesPriceLevel" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>VAT:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtModalPricesVAT" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sales Unit: </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownPLvlSalesUnit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quantity: </td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtModalPricesQuantity" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Inc. Price: </td>
                <td><input ID="txtModalPricesIncPrice" name="txtModalPricesIncPrice" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ex. Price: </td>
                <td><input ID="txtModalPricesExPrice" name="txtModalPricesExPrice" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Profit: </td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtModalPricesProfit" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Margin: </td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtModalPricesMargin" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Target:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtModalPricesTarget" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCRIPT1014: Invalid character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261256/script1014-invalid-character)

Comment: nope - saw that post but no answer for this on that post, he solved it by using a http server, i also tried the encoding option

Comment: Is this available online somewhere? I'm afraid by the given info and code this question can't be answered.

Comment: its still in VS2010 at the minute, but the code is the excat same as here http://jsfiddle.net/xCq5H/ without any errors

Comment: So what is the problem? The jsfiddle does not trigger any console errors on IE 9.

Comment: thats the point... but when i place this inside my own full page the error kicks in :/

Comment: is this the correct way to declare the script??