# Ember 1.12 does not work on IE11

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I upgraded my Ember 1.08 web app to Ember 1.12. On 1.08 it worked on all browsers, but on 1.12, it does not work in IE11 anymore.

I get `SCRIPT1014 (invalid character)` on:

```
 let CONTAINER = `__${new Date()}_container`;
```

And I get `SCRIPT5009 (define is not defined)` on:

```
 define('xxx/adapters/yyy', ['exports', 'xxx/adapters/base/zzz-adapter'], function (exports, zzz) {
```

Upgrading to Ember 1.13 is not an option in the near term. Is anyone else having problems with Ember 1.12 and IE11?

Please note, it looks like a problem with Babel, but I am using EmberCLI and Babel should work automatically.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning temp folder, bower components and node modules and reinstalling them? Sometimes it helps after upgrade.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache? See a similar question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834261/getting-script1014-invalid-character-in-ie-from-local-js-file).

Comment: Yes I did npm and bower clean and delete temp folder. Still babel seems not to kick in and I get ES6 output which IE11 does not understand.

Comment: I also cleared the IE11 browser cache, made no difference, still not working in IE11 (because of ES6 code)

Comment: I fixed it myself, after an upgrade of ember-cli babel worked again.