# Handlebars single quote issue

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm having difficulty processing an onclick event where paramater values are passed through to a custom function via handlebars.  I've also tried to escape the quotes and use triple brackets {{{Surname}}}}

The following will break if the surname is: O'Neill

```
{{#each employee}}
    <div onclick="populateForm('{{Firstname}}', '{{Surname}}');">test for {{Firstname}} {{Surname}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

I've tried various combinations of single and double quotes to build my event handler but can't get this to work.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to pass in the entire person object as in 

    `<div onclick="populateForm('{{this}}');">` and retrieve each property individually in your populateForm function like: `person.Firstname` and so on

Comment: I liked this idea but couldn't get it to work in practise.  
populateForm('{{this}}') results in: populateForm('[object Object]'); 
I've tried to access the array via dot notation but it always seemed to return the string representation of [object Object], regardless if i wrapped the onclick in single quotations or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with single and double quotes, you can also use the Acute character (`) in your statement.

The below Handlebars code works fine,

```
{{#each employee}}
    <div onclick="alert(`{{{Firstname}}}`, `{{Surname}}`);">test for {{{Firstname}}} {{Surname}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

with this sample JSON

```
{
  "employee": [
    {
      "Firstname": "a",
      "Surname": "b"
    },
    {
      "Firstname": "o'neill",
      "Surname": "d"
    }
  ]
}
```

Tested using http://tryhandlebarsjs.com.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware of the Acute character but it's working perfectly!

Comment: Spoke to soon! I've tested in Internet explorer 11 and I get the error SCRIPT1014: Invalid character when using the Acute character :(

Comment: Try it this way. `<div onclick='alert("{{{Firstname}}}", "{{Surname}}");'>test for {{{Firstname}}} {{Surname}}</div>`

Comment: Also please check whether this question helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834261/getting-script1014-invalid-character-in-ie-from-local-js-file

Comment: onclick='alert("{{{Surname}}}");' <- doesn't work, the error is now:  SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant.  Presumably the single quote in the surname causes the string to terminate e.g. onclick='alert("O'Neill");'

Comment: Can you try with double brackets and not triple ones, with both acute and single quotes?

Comment: tried double brackets qith acute and single quotes, same a before, works fine in Chrome/Firefox but presence of acute character cause IE to throw error message in console.

Comment: Sorry mate, then the only option ahead is to write a helper to convert the quote character to HTML encoded one and render in the Handlebars with triple brackets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166253/discussion-between-gibin-ealias-and-scott).