# IE11: certain elements not being displayed, but after clearing history it works perfect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, browser-history

I've created a website which uses html5, jquery, php, etc. which works fine on Firefox and Google Chrome, but recently I've been experiencing problems with internet explorer 11.

The site first requires you to log in, after which it refreshes the page. The problem in IE11 (and possible earlier versions) is that some dynamic elements (like divs, tables, ...) are not being displayed, while others are.

Now, when I'm on the login page and delete my browser history (only history, not cookies or temporary files or such) and then login, the site works perfect, identical to firefox and google chrome.

Because of this, my guess is this isn't a programming problem, but something to do with loading scripts or such. The strange thing is that some functions do work from some file, yet others don't.

Does somebody know what might be the problem?

Comment: Tried checking the console via F12 in internet explorer to see if you are getting any errors?

Comment: I get the error: SCRIPT1014: invalid character rule 1, column 1. Yet this error also shows when the site works fine after deleting the history.

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261256/script1014-invalid-character

Comment: I'm trying to find what causes this fault (there's a lot of code). But I don't think this error causes the problem, since I still get it when the site works.

Comment: In short the post i linked had a script that was linked by file path and not web path, that may not be the issue but in any case, errors with javascript do strange things, so all errors should be fixed just to rule it out. who knows where IE12 will handle errors differently and your site could stop working when the browser is automatically upgraded.

Comment: I found out what caused the error, it were embeded youtube clips. Disabling these did not fix the problem though...

Comment: can you add a 'no cache' attribute to the page to see if the cache is causing the problem? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk.aspx