# Dynamic Div with different paragraphs in Javascript Only

Tags: javascript, html, json, class

I want to dynamically add paragraphs with their respective icons inside each a div. For example, if the service returns 30 items, then I will create 30 div class ="tile" . If the service returns 1 then it will create just one.

```
<Body>
    <div class="contain">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row__inner">
                <div class="tile">
                    <i id ="icon" class="fas fa-passport fa-2x"></i>
                    <p id="name" class="title-text ">UnitMainx </p>
                    <h2 id="id" class="unitdesc">x..45..322.2</h2>
                    <p class="small-text ">more</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</Body>
```

I would like to create one of this depending on the length of my service  response. The part that I find difficult is to pass the values from the service inside the div.

```
<Script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
    function processRequest(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            response.forEach(myFunction);
            function myFunction(item, index) {
                document.getElementById("name").innerHTML +=item.name;
                document.getElementById("id").innerHTML += item.id; 
                document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML += if 
                    (item.name == "UnitMainx" ){ then add fa fa  icon };   
            }
        }
    }
</Script>
```

Comment: whats wrong with you your existing code. Assuming you are learning js

Comment: Nothing is wrong so far, all I want to know is how to create each div with name and id from the item the list. I'm creating a horizontal slider with those values.so if for ex: the service returns 3 items. then create 3 div exactly as I added in the body.

Comment: `myHTML += '<div class="name">' + item.name + '</div>'`, Dont use id's in loop since ids are unique, and when you are done with forEach add them to the contain class `document.querySelctor('.contain').innerHTML = myHTML`

Comment: @joyBlanks could you be able to show me in what part should I add the document.querySelctor('.contain').innerHTML = myHTML you mentioned after the foreach.but I couldnt quite get it

Comment: @joyBlanks seems that the template doesn't work with internet explorer . as @saasgroup mentioned below. How can I create the same thing without using the ` for the template? thanks

Comment: add as a string `html += '<div class="'+something+'">' + name +'<div>'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that creates multiple instances of the same class. it bypasses the styling of the columns . in other words is put in the columns on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your html create in dynamically from the api response and when you are done push it back to a coantiner div

See here i used a ` tick as when `html += ...` for the html because I want to use it like a template and then I can use values from api response with loop variable `${row.name}` and so on

I also used `fetch` which is now native in most browsers instead of `XMLhttpRequest` coz its a lot of code. You can fallback to xhr if you want but the inner logic is what you should be looking at

```
<body>
  <div class="contain">
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    let html = '';
    for (const row of data) {
      html += `
      <div class="row" id="${row.id}">
        <div class="row__inner">
          <div class="tile">
            <i id ="icon" class="fas fa-passport fa-2x"></i>
            <p id="name" class="title-text ">${row.name}</p>
            <h2 id="id" class="unitdesc">x..45..322.2</h2>
            <p class="small-text ">more</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      `
    }
    document.querySelector('.contain').innerHTML = html;
  })
</script>
```

Update for IE where tick doesn't work

```
html += '<div class="row" id="' + row.id + '">'
  + '<div class="row__inner">'
  + '<div class="tile">'
  + '<i id ="icon" class="fas fa-passport fa-2x"></i>'
  + '<p id="name" class="title-text ">' + row.name + '</p>'
  + '<h2 id="id" class="unitdesc">x..45..322.2</h2>'
  + '<p class="small-text ">more</p>'
  + '</div>'
  + '</div>'
  + '</div>'
```

Comment: You are a genie!!! Thanks a lot. I will have to figure out how to incorporate my CSS into your snippet. Pretty cool.

Comment: I think you are new to JS would recommend read some tutorials before you code would help write you better code

Answer (score 0):

how can you change the template ? because literals are blocked in internet explorer and trows as error [SCRIPT1014: Invalid character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261256/script1014-invalid-character)
it sounds weird but how can you change that template to still be dynamic without the character`

Comment: any other  ideas about how to use it without those ` thicks @joyBlanks?

Comment: @joyBlanks the issue is with the new example the first class repeats itself 20 times or whatever # items comes with the service. and if you add the + before each <p> then you get NAN and next the name of item.

Comment: same issue here with the example