# Create flex-box columns from Json response javascript

Tags: javascript, css, json, flexbox, multiple-columns

Create a set of columns based on a json response ex: `foreach(var item in json )then {create div + item.id + item.icon+div}`. NOTE: can't use a template that starts with (thicks ``) because that causes error on IE11 . don't know why.

I tried:

> ### For each item in the list create one column with the text inside

```
let container+=
 +  '<div class=" ">'
 + ' <p class=" child ">text from json </p> '
```

> ### display each column with those values

```
 document.querySelector('.flex-container').innerHTML = container;
```

Actual results
I tried a similar example in here
[question]:[Dynamic Div with different paragraphs in Javascript Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57880898/dynamic-div-with-different-paragraphs-in-javascript-only/57931351#57931351). but unfortunately, the answer there is not working for me. I expect the output to look like this
https://www.w3schools.com/csS/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox, so instead of showing 1, 2,3 in each column, I want to show the text above in the paragraph. ex: if Json is 30 items, then I will show 30 columns with their respective styling.

Comment: `Create a set of columns` show your CSS IN your question as this is key to your quesiton

Comment: you should also post whatever  HTML '.flex-container' is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not say how you get the text from the JSON so I will leave that to you and assume an array of text, so here is how to append that to an element (made an assumption there also as your question is less than complete.

```js
function appendNewThing(jsonTxt) {
  let container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "child-holder";
  let newP = document.createElement("p");
  newP.className = "child";
  let newContent = document.createTextNode(jsonTxt);
  newP.appendChild(newContent);
  container.appendChild(newP);
  document.getElementsByClassName("flex-container")[0].appendChild(container);
}

let textFromJSON = ["J Text 1", "My 2", "Text 3", "Last 4"];
textFromJSON.forEach(appendNewThing)
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #73A3FF;
}

.flex-container>.child-holder {
  background-color: #D3f4FF;
  margin: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.child-holder {
  border: 1px solid #5577FF;
}

.child {
  color: #0000FF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
</div>
```